# Grab next record thru table in while loop insert statement

Tags: sql, insert

Trying to grab the next Code in this dataset. As of now the insert statement is only grabbing the 1st one and not the next one. Here is my code:

```
Declare @ID int

Declare @NumOfSeq int

Declare @Code nvarchar(250)

create table #ID_TempTable (ID int) 

insert into #ID_TempTable select distinct ID from STX_JJ_Keller_Training

    WHILE @@rowcount > 0 -- Still have ID exist
    BEGIN
        SET ROWCOUNT 1;
        select @ID = ID from #ID_TempTable
        print 'ID equals  ' + cast(@ID as varchar)
        delete from #ID_TempTable where ID = @ID
        if exists (select 1 from HRET_10_21 where HRCo = 2 and HRRef = @ID)
        BEGIN
            select @NumOfSeq = Count(1) from STRL_Training_Active where ID = @ID
            Declare @cnt INT = 0;
            Declare @maxSeq INT;
            select @maxSeq =  max(Seq) from HRET_10_21 where HRCo = 2 and HRRef = @ID
            While @cnt < @NumOfSeq
            BEGIN
                set @cnt = @cnt + 1; 
                BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
                SET ROWCOUNT 1;
                insert into
                    HRET_10_21
                    (HRCo,HRRef,Seq,TrainCode,[Status],[Date],CompleteDate,
                    [Type],DegreeYN,Cost,ReimbursedYN,Instructor1099YN,
                    VendorGroup,OSHAYN,MSHAYN,FirstAidYN,CPRYN,WorkRelatedYN)
                select
                    2 as HRCo,
                    ID as HRRef,
                    @maxSeq + @cnt as Seq,
                    Code as TrainCode,
                    case when  Completed is not null then 'C' else 'S' end as Status,
                    [Enrollment Date] as Date,
                    Completed as CompleteDate,
                    'T' as Type, 'N' as DegreeYN, 0 as Cost,
                    'N' as ReimbursedYN ,'N' AS Instructor1099YN,
                    1 as VendorGroup, 'N' AS OSHAYN,
                    'N' AS MSHAYN,'N' AS FirstAidYN,
                    'N' AS CPRYN, 'Y' AS WorkRelatedYN
                from
                    STRL_Training_Active
                where
                     ID = @ID
                COMMIT;
            END -- end of while
        END  -- end of if
        else
        BEGIN
            select @NumOfSeq = Count(1) from STRL_Training_Active where ID = @ID
            Declare @cnt2 INT = 0;
            While @cnt2 < @NumOfSeq
            BEGIN
                set @cnt2 = @cnt2 + 1; 
                BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
                SET ROWCOUNT 1;
                insert into
                    HRET_10_21
                    (HRCo,HRRef,Seq,TrainCode,[Status],[Date],CompleteDate,
                    [Type],DegreeYN,Cost,ReimbursedYN,Instructor1099YN,
                    VendorGroup,OSHAYN,MSHAYN,FirstAidYN,CPRYN,WorkRelatedYN)
                select
                    HRCo,
                    ID as HRRef,
                    @cnt2 as Seq,
                    Code as TrainCode,
                    case when  Completed is not null then 'C' else 'S' end as Status,
                    [Enrollment Date] as Date,
                    Completed as CompleteDate,
                    'T' as Type, 'N' as DegreeYN, 0 as Cost,
                    'N' as ReimbursedYN ,'N' AS Instructor1099YN,
                    1 as VendorGroup, 'N' AS OSHAYN,
                    'N' AS MSHAYN,'N' AS FirstAidYN,
                    'N' AS CPRYN, 'Y' AS WorkRelatedYN
                from
                    STRL_Training_Active
                where
                     ID = @ID
                COMMIT;
            END -- end of while
        END -- end of else
        --select 1 from #ID_TempTable
    END
    drop table #ID_TempTable
```

[Picture of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbSYD.png)